# Ignore time portion of DateTime in linq query

Tags: .net, linq, sorting, datetime

I'm trying to sort "organizations" by the date portion of `DateAdded` (which is of type `DateTime`) while ignoring the time. After that primary sort, I want to sort by the organization's name.

This is what I currently have, but it also sorts based on the time:

```
IQueryable<Organization> organizations = from m in context.Organizations
    orderby m.OrgName ascending
    orderby m.DateAdded ascending
    select m;
```

The above almost works, but it sorts on the time, too.

Comment: Depends on your IQueryProvider. Entity Framework? link to sql?

Comment: m.DateAdded .Date should do the trick it its a datetime

Comment: Won't work unless the IQueryProvider supports that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IQueryable<Organization> organizations = context.Organizations
    .Orderby( m => m.DateAdded.Date )
    .ThenBy( m => m.OrgName );
```

I see you're using `IQueryable` which hints you're using Entity Framework (Linq-to-Entities) where (I believe) `DateTime.Date` doesn't work, but you can use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

IQueryable<Organization> organizations = context.Organizations
    .Orderby( m => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime( m.DateAdded ) )
    .ThenBy( m => m.OrgName );
```

Comment: That was really close, Dai. You still had ".Date" which I had to remove, and I had to call TruncateTime slightly differently. This worked: IQueryable<Organization> organizations = context.Organizations.OrderBy(m => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.DateAdded)).ThenBy(m => m.OrgName)

Comment: @SteveA Thank you for testing it :) I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's EntityFramework you can use

EntityFunctions.TruncateTime on the Date